# How can I delimit a transparent area on png image when I'm using HTML 5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, png

I'm having some issues when I'm trying to delimit a area in html5 canvas, I have this img: 
[image]

I want to get transparency only in white parts of img, not on all img.
I'm drawing the img in this part of code:

```
    this.draw = function(){
        context.save();
        context.drawImage(sniperScoop, 0, 0, w,h);      
        context.restore();
    }
```

That is possible using HTML 5 Canvas/Javascript ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you saving the context and then restoring it? Is this the full draw function or just part of it?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me. I think you want to take the above image and set the rgb(255,255,255) areas to have an opacity of 0. If so, draw the image to a canvas, get the canvas's data and then examine all of the pixels to see if they satisfy the (white) requirement. If so, simply set the alpha value for that array element to 0. Each pixel has 4 array elements, r, g, b and a. Therefore, the index of the first element (r) is calculated by: `index = ((y * canvasWidthPixels) + x) * 4;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd just edit the image with a program like gimp and cut out the white part. Is there any reason not to do it this way?

Comment: I tried, but all image still transparent and i want only the white circle (that i cutted of with GIMP)

Comment: Oh, you have done this. Sorry, I should've checked. Are you saying that it is still drawing white over the canvas where the image is transparent? That seems wrong..